# How to read text file with multiple whitespaces python/spark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, data-wrangling

I have `.txt` file which I tried to read using python/spark but it was either convetered to one big string or I  was not able to data in right format.

I noticed in data file sometime there are multiple white spaces.

##### DataSet

```
import io
data_str = """value          code    description                 version     plant        ing_code       weight                   created              end               
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei PreStart Kruimel      170        Wan         2132.00          19.800000000010389 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000   
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei PreStart Kruimel      170        Wan          1808.00          0.55000000000025961 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000 
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei PreStart Kruimel      170        Wan          1672.00         5.9999999999999998E-2 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000    
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei 3 Meel                370        Wan          1253.00          1.21 2020-07-29 06:30:10.000 2020-07-29 06:30:10.000    
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei 3 Meel                370        Wan           1582.00        9.9000000000061018E-3 2020-07-29 06:30:10.000 2020-07-29 06:30:10.000    
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei Start Meel            570        Wan          2132.00         24.800000000000001 2020-07-29 06:32:38.000 2020-07-29 06:32:38.000"""
data_io = io.StringIO(data_str)
```

##### Code

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(data_io)
df_pd = pd.read_csv(data_io,  sep='\s\s+')
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestion

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try passing this option in the `read_csv` function call? 
`delim_whitespace=True`

Comment: but then how do you differentiate the 3rd column which has whitespace in the values

Comment: in your data you have single space between `code` and `description` columns so your regexp not valid as separator, but if you change it to `\s+` you will get extra data in the `description` looks like you need some processing of the input data

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your file is a Fixed Width File. That is, if you open it in a text editor, the column widths will all be the same (instead of using a separator like `,`or `\s`). Pandas comes with a built-in function for reading Fixed Width Files: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_fwf("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/df.txt")
```

### Edit

Thanks for uploading the string, it makes debugging more exact! Some of your columns have values with single spaces, and some columns are separated by single spaces. You won't be able to use a pandas built-in function, but you can parse the data on your own with regex. For example:

```
import io
import re
data_str = """value          code    description                 version     plant        ing_code       weight                   created              end               
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei PreStart Kruimel      170        Wan         2132.00          19.800000000010389 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000   
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei PreStart Kruimel      170        Wan          1808.00          0.55000000000025961 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000 
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei PreStart Kruimel      170        Wan          1672.00         5.9999999999999998E-2 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000 2020-07-27 14:15:55.000    
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei 3 Meel                370        Wan          1253.00          1.21 2020-07-29 06:30:10.000 2020-07-29 06:30:10.000    
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei 3 Meel                370        Wan           1582.00        9.9000000000061018E-3 2020-07-29 06:30:10.000 2020-07-29 06:30:10.000    
NULL             (Nxt) Optigroei Start Meel            570        Wan          2132.00         24.800000000000001 2020-07-29 06:32:38.000 2020-07-29 06:32:38.000"""

line_regex = re.compile("(\w+)\s+\((\w+)\)\s+((?:[\w]+\s){0,3})\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+([\d\.]+)\s+([\d\.E-]+)\s([\d-]+ [\d:\.]+)\s([\d-]+ [\d:\.]+)")
data = []
for i, line in enumerate(data_str.split("\n")):
    if not i: # get header from first line
        columns = re.split("\s+", line.strip())
    else:
        data.append(re.match(line_regex, line).groups())
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

You can modify each regex capture group to match your expected data type in that column. I like to use https://pythex.org as a playground to try regexes.

Comment: last columns not separated, btw I updated the OP question now you can easy test it yourself

Comment: Added an example for handling through regex.